# MATLAB: How to find node cycles in graph that don't form face?

Tags: matlab, graph, graph-theory

How can I find node cycles of a graph that don't form a face? given :

```
Vu = [1.0582    0.7096    0.9404;1.1116    0.8902    0.8852;1.3265    0.7470    0.9291;1.3651    0.9047    0.8713;2.6738    0.9412    0.7881;2.6782    0.8999    0.8283;2.6798    0.8554    0.8686;2.6817    0.9652    0.7497;2.8176    0.9350    0.7807;2.8624    0.9040    0.8127;2.8627    0.9457    0.7625;2.8776    0.9563    0.7442;3.0046    0.9088    0.8014;3.0255    0.8674    0.8463;3.0337    0.9338    0.7699;3.1505    0.8888    0.8260;3.2049    0.9098    0.8020;3.2361    0.8767    0.8367;3.2452    0.8583    0.8473;3.3133    0.8806    0.8268;3.3811    0.8379    0.8384;3.3907    0.9090    0.7962;3.5508    0.8351    0.8182]

edge_list = [4 8;7 8; 3 7;3 4;5 8;8 12;9 12;5 9;13 15;11 13;11 12;12 15;17 22;22 23;21 23;17 21;18 19;18 20;20 21;19    21;13 18;14 19;13 14;6  7;6 13;7 14;16 18;16 17;17 20;13 16;15 17;6 10;5 6;9 10;10 13;9 11;2 4;1 3;1    2];

faces = [17 21 22 23; 18 19 20 21; 16 17 18 20; 13 15 16 17; 14 19 18 13;14 7 6 13;10 13 9 11; 5 9 10 16; 15 13 11 12; 9 5 12 8; 7 3 4 8; 1 2 3 4];

G = graph(edge_list(:,1), edge_list(:,2));
figure(1);
plot(G);
```

The graph is:
[image]

The non-face node cycles would be `[17 20 21]`, `[16 18 13]`, `[9,11,12]`, `[5 6 7 8]`, `[6 10 13]` in above case.

Update: Definition of faces here is non-overlapping polygons.

Comment: How do you define which are faces and which aren’t? With a different embedding of your graph, any of those cycles could be faces.

Comment: Faces are in the faces array. Basically I want to find the cycles that could have been a face but aren't in the faces array.